# Update emacs that comes with OS X

Tags: macos, emacs

Is there a way to update the emacs terminal editor that comes with OS X? I could remove the binaries and install Emacs using a `dmg` package, but the idea was to upgrade to a newer version with some command.

Answer (score 12):

Apple controls when / if they update `emacs` so most people just install a newer version of the tool and change their PATH variable so the new version is found first and runs by default.

If you like the sound of that, I recommend installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install emacs:

```
brew install emacs
```

Add a link so that it'll work as `emacs` in the Terminal:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app /Applications
```

This will install the 'stable' version. As of this writing, that's 24.5:

```
» brew info emacs
emacs: stable 24.5 (bottled), devel 25.0-dev, HEAD
GNU Emacs text editor
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/
```

This is significantly newer (24.5.1) than the version that came with El Capitan (22.1.1):

```
» emacs --version
GNU Emacs 22.1.1
```

Comment: However doesn't this mean that typing emacs in Terminal will find the Apple supplied one first. Also you should explain why use Homebrew rather than a binary emacs and why you can't just copy that emacs over Apple's one

Comment: @Mark Because it's far more convenient than... really anything else. Testing whether it'll find the HB version first.

Comment: After testing it, there's one more command to link it. Edited, thank you.

Comment: surely you need more than that as you emacs in Applications is not on the path

Comment: Forgive the edit - I've made the rationale for adding a second binary to the top of this post @nbro - Short of lobbying apple to update the app, you could install this and then shove it in place of the shipping version. On 10.11 that binary is restricted by default - so you need to disable SIP and deal with weakening Apple's security model. The downside is large to messing with Apple's shipping OS. The upside to layering new tools that run instead of the shipping ones is large.

Comment: No worries, thank you @bmike. That's said much better than I could have said it.

Comment: You can also compile from source.  XCode has all the necessary tools.  This also gives a GUI version which is nicer than the terminal-only version supplied by Apple.

Comment: You can use `brew linkapps` instead of creating a symlink. That way it's not version dependant.

Comment: It seems that you have to use `brew install emacs --with-cocoa` to get the `Emacs.app` folder (I tried to install on OS X High Sierra). However, the `ln` example did not make the homebrew emacs the default one, but I had to add an alias
`$ alias emacs="/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/26.1_1/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"
`

Comment: Apparently `Emacs.app` is not included anymore when installing emacs, at least in v26.3. What worked for me, instead of the `ln` command, was:
`$ alias emacs="/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/26.3/bin/emacs"` (you have to replace 26.3 with your version of emacs)
Also, if you want this alias to be permanent, you need to add it to `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, or whichever you're using.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done but best not to do it. Certain directories including /usr/bin are updated and controlled by Apple so any changes there will be removed when the OS is updated, also in El Capitan and above this path is locked down by SiP and so you have to go through more hoops to chnage files there.

```
$ ls -lO /usr/bin/emacs
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted,compressed 35581744 Jan 13 20:12 /usr/bin/emacs
```

However in practice there is no need to do this. Install a new emacs in places you have access to e.g. for command line in /usr/local/bin or ~/bin - or GUI versions in /Applications or ~/Applications. /usr/local/bin is the default path so in all cases you need to edit the path to put the directory containing emacs before /usr/bin.

Answer (score -3):

When using the brew command the correct command is `brew upgrade emacs` even if you have done a `brew update`, the install will install Emacs 25, the older version.

Just sharing my experience.

Comment: Could you bee a bit more specific in your question as to what you are doing, what you expect and what you get.

Comment: Verified on macOS 11.13.6: `brew upgrade emacs` will fail if there is no brew-installed emacs available, `brew install emacs` will install the most recent version (emacs-26.1_1 right now).